# How can I force the <span> to fit in div (the content being jinja variables)

Tags: html, css, jinja2

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 150%;" style="display:table;">
      <div class="card-header" style="display:table;">
        <p class="display-4 bold" style="font-size: 30px;">Voici la transcription et traduction :</p> 
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item" style="display: inline-block;">
          ADN
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1" style="font-size: 15px;display: inline-block;">{{ generationdata[0] }}</span>
          </div>
          
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item" style="display: inline-block;">
          ARN
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1" style="font-size: 15px;display: inline-block;">{{ generationdata[1] }}</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item" style="display: table;width: fit-content; ">
          Protéine
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1" style="font-size: 15px;display: inline-block;width: fit-content; ">{{ generationdata[2] }}</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

This is what I get but I would want the content to be displayed on another line if too long for the div width:
[image: This is what I get but I would want the content to be displayed on another line if too long for the div width]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe adding this to your css would fix your issue

```
.list-group-item {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

alternatively you could add `word-wrap:break-word;` to each individual style of the `spans`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now I had to remove the list-group-flush class.